# How to start cron in Linux Mint 17.3

Tags: cron

How can I start cron at startup of computer, so I can use a cronjob to automatically make a backup using rsync. I am not well known with how to start programs in Linux. I am using Linux Mint 17.3.

Comment: The cron *daemon* should be started automatically during the normal boot process. Are you asking how to create a *cronjob* that is run on reboot?

Comment: I know how to create a cronjob. But if I look which processes are running cron isn't among them so I think that is why my cronjob as root is not starting at the time I want it to start.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use cron because rsync can do backup when computer starts by running daemon. You should look at this forum post: [Click here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1252720)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am going to try what is written in the forum post.

Answer (score 0):

If you have cron installed (which it normally is), you can make an entry in your crontab file that starts with `@reboot` (instead of the more usual minute/hour/day/month/day-of-week specification). That job will be run on bootup. You can find more information on this with `man 5 crontab` from the commandline.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am going to read that manpage.